# Task Assignment Notification email

Tags: email, task-notifications

Task Assignment Notification email are not being received by user(not the end user creating the task) despite the "notify me when someone assign me a task" permission is being checked.Please let me know what might be the issue or is there any workaround by which we can send task assignment notification email?This issue is in Salesforce classic.

Comment: can you please check Email Administration-> Deliverability -> Access level is set to "All Emails"

Comment: @ Santanu Boral:It is set to "All Emails" only but still no luck

Comment: Did you create any email alerts for task notifications? Only  "notify me when someone assign me a task" permission will not serve the issue

Comment: I have created an email alert for notifying related contact to a task and related contacts are receiving emails.However as per the sales force documentation task assignment notification emails are automatically send without any email alert.Not sure whether I am missing out on anything.

Comment: Did you resolve the issue? I am stuck with the same.